# Incorrect verification code error - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We recently upgraded our Wordpress multisite to 4.0.1 and since then we are unable to create new users. Whenever we try to create new user, irrespective of site, we get "Incorrect verification code" error. I was searching on internet for this error but no luck. Could some please advise?

Comment: Looks some issue with plugin used, try deactivating all of them.

Comment: I did deactivate all plugins on one site but it didnt work. Are you suggesting to deactivate on the entire wordpress?